# Git - display commiter when commiting

Tags: git

I work with different git identities, and since I sometimes manage to mix them up, is there a way to display this information when commiting?

Along the list of modified files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can use the `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-message` git hook with such content:

```
 WHOAMI="# $(git config user.name) <$(git config user.email)>"
 echo "$WHOAMI" >> "$1"
```

This adds, at the end of the pre-formatted commit message, the line

```
# username <user@email.com>
```

See `man githooks` and `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample` for further information and examples.

Answer (score 4):

How do you switch identities? If you're using separate repositories, you can set `user.name` and `user.email` in the `.git/config` file for each one and not bother.

Otherwise, you can set the `commit.template` option to a file which contains some markers and then change your `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-message` [hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) to edit the file in place and insert your username/email in it.

Comment: I have several machines, with different configurations and some repos have local configurations, and I tend to checkout a lot, so it's a big mess.